# Creating Hashmap using existing hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I created a hashmap as shown below:

```
Map<String, String> streetno = new HashMap<String, String>();

streetno.put("3", "Sachin");
streetno.put("2", "Dravid");
streetno.put("1", "Sehwag");
streetno.put("5", "Laxman");
streetno.put("4", "Kohli");
```

Now I want to create a new hashmap where key of the above hashmap becomes value and value becomes key as shown below:

```
Map<String, String> streetname = new HashMap<String, String>();

streetname.put("Sachin", "3");
streetname.put("Dravid", "2");
streetname.put("Sehwag", "1");
streetname.put("Laxman", "5");
streetname.put("Kohli", "4");
```

I don't know how to do that.. Can anyone help me out with this..

Comment: Note that guava, the google collections api, supports the notion of a BiMap that supports an `inverse()` operation to do just this. Usefully it does this without making a copy of the data. See [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html#inverse()) for api details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> streetname = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (Entry<String,String> e : streetno.entrySet()) {
  streetname.put(e.getValue(), e.getKey());
}
```

Here, the `for` loop iterates over all entries (i.e. key/value pairs) in the original map, and inserts them into the second map with the key and value swapped over.

It is probably a good idea to check that `put()` returns `null`. If you get a non-null value, this means that the values in `streetno` are not unique. Since this is homework, I leave it to you to figure out the consequences, and how best to handle this.

Comment: Ah I don't like it when somebody just solves the homework. Help a bit, but do not do all the work. After all it is homework so that the student will put some effort in it.

Comment: I hope your original values are unique; otherwise you're loosing data

Answer (score 2):

Perfect you are almost there. Now you need to iterate the first hash map keys and simulate what you have done in those 5 lines:

```
streetname.put("Sachin", "3");
streetname.put("Dravid", "2");
streetname.put("Sehwag", "1");
streetname.put("Laxman", "5");
streetname.put("Kohli", "4");
```

Tip: iteration over map might be a bit tricky for you, but usually it is done like that:

```
for (String key : streetno.keySet()) {
...
}
```

Good luck with your homework!

Comment: I didn't downvote you but... perhaps the downvoter took offence to `streetno.keySet()` you should really be using `streetno.entrySet()` otherwise you're going to have to access the map again to get the value.

Comment: This is true, probably it will be a bit slower, but I think this will be good enough for homework. I Wanted to avoid the `entrySet`, because I was afraid I will confuse the student (I don't know his level of expertise). Even with my solution the complexity stays O(n).

Answer (score 0):

**Java 8:**

```
Map<String, String> streetname = 
    streetno.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
```

Note:

If you are tempted to use `parellelstream()` instead of `stream()` think twice about it. This would only be appropriate if your `Map` is extremely large.